# converting int to float/double

Tags: php

I am running into troubles when I want to convert `integer` values to `float` (numbers with dots).

```
$a = 7200;
$b = $a/3600;

echo $b; // 2

$b = floatval($b);

echo $b; // 2
```

But it should echo `2.0` or `2.00`

I also tried settype, without success.
And I am finding only help/solutions/questions for "float to int".

Comment: 2 and 2.0 are the same number float or not.  I understand that you are not seeing the decimal as you like, but the math you are doing is coming up with an int for a quotient.  Do you experience the same when dividing by floating point numbers?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

***Updated:***

**Use**

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", $b); // returns 2.00
```

<strike>Use</strike>

```
echo number_format($b, 2);
```

eg:

```
echo number_format(1234, 2); // returns 1,234.00
```

**Edit:**

@DavidBaucum Yes, number_format() returns string.

Use

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", $b);
```

For your question, use

> Why number_format doesn't work can be demonstrated by this. echo
>   number_format(1234,0) + 1.0 The result is 2

```
echo sprintf("%.2f",(1234 + 1.0 ) ); // returns 1235.00
```

Comment: number_format returns a string, never a float.

Comment: Why `number_format` doesn't work can be demonstrated by this. `echo number_format(1234,0) + 1.0` The result is `2`.

Comment: @DavidBaucum I updated my answer and thanks for pointing my mistake :)

Comment: But `sprintf` returns `string` as well!

Comment: why everyone answers with output? What if I wanted to format a variable?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) function to accomplish this. This function also allows you to define the number of zeroes to be displayed after the decimal -- you just need to use the second parameter for that:

```
$a = 7200;
$b = $a/3600;
$b = floatval($b);
echo number_format($b, 2, '.', '');
```

Or, if you want to do it one line:

```
echo number_format( (float) $b, 2, '.', '');
```

Output:

```
2.00
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54890)

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```
<?php
    $a = 7200;
    $b = $a/3600;

    $b = number_format($b,2);

    echo $b; // 2.00
?>
```

-

```
number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by myself:

```
    $b = number_format((float)$b, 1, '.', '');
echo $b; // 2.0
```

does the trick

Comment: After So many google searches, This helped !!! Thanks Buddy