# check php post value is numeric and well formatted

Tags: php

I need to check POST value is numeric and well formatted. My expected format is

```
number.number
1.0
11.5
```

If POST value comes without `.(DOT)` only `1` then I would want that php convert that to `1.0`

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$foo = '2';
$foo = preg_match('/\\d{2}\\:\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}/', $foo);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `echo number_format($foo,1);`

Comment: not sure how many decimal places you're dealing with but number_format() could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code

```
//$value = '22';
$value = $_POST["input_value"];
if (is_numeric($value)) {

    $new_value = number_format($value, 1);

} else {

    $new_value = "$value is not numeric. <br>";

}

echo $new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to check if the variable from the POST array is a float/double or not (float/double is a type of number in the format of x.x).

**Cheking if a string is a float/double number**

To do that, use this php built-in function: [is_double](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-double.php) or more accurate:[is_float](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), that will tell you if the string is a float/double.

**Checking if a string is an integer and converting it to a double/float value**

If it's not a double, check if it's an integer (regular number): [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), and if it's indeed an int, cast it to double by using `number_format`, look at the usage here: [integer to double/float in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409574/converting-int-to-float-double).

**Example**

```
$final_value;
$value = $_POST["wanted_value"];
if (is_float($value))
{
    $final_value = $value;
}
else if (is_int($value))
{
    $final_value = number_format($value, 1); // or 2 instead of 1 (2.0 or 2.00)
}
else
{
    $final_value = "ERROR";
}
```

Hope this helps!